# Create PDF with iText on iSeries leads to error "The document has no pages."

Tags: itext, ibm-midrange

We use the nice library iText for one of my customer's project to generate a pdf from a string representing a html page. The iText version is 5.5.10.

The following piece of code works well on the development environments and servers running on Windows, but it is not working on the customer's server running on iSeries.

```
    public class GeneratePDFCmdImpl extends ControllerCommandImpl implements
    GeneratePDFCmd {

        private String charsetStr = null;
        private Charset charset = null;
        private BaseFont bf = null;
        private String destFile = null;
        private String destFilename = null;
        private String srcContent = null;
        private String docName = null;

        public void setDocName(String docname) {
            this.docName = docname;
        }

        public void setSrcContent(String srcContent) {
            this.srcContent = srcContent;
        }

        private void prepareDefaultsAndSettings() {

            /* srcContent may be more complex html but even this simple one is not working */
            srcContent = "<html><head></head><body>This is just a test</body></html>";
            docName = "mypdf";

            charsetStr = "UTF-8";

            destFilename = docName+".pdf";          

            Date timestamp = new Date();

            /* destFile = "/" is just for the sample. In my real project, the value is a folder where my app has full rights
            */
            destFile = "/" + destFilename;
            charset = Charset.forName(charsetStr);

            FontFactory.register("/fonts/arial.ttf","Arial");
            bf = FontFactory.getFont("Arial").getBaseFont();

        }

        @Override
        public void performExecute() throws ECException {
            super.performExecute();

            Document document =  null;
            OutputStream os = null;

            prepareDefaultsAndSettings();

            try { 


                InputStream srcInputStream;     
                srcInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(srcContent.getBytes(charset));


                document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 75, 80);

                FileOutputStream destOutput =  new FileOutputStream(destFile);

                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,destOutput);
                writer.setPageEvent( new HeaderFooterPageEvent(bf));

                document.open();  
                XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, srcInputStream, charset);           
                document.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if(document != null) {
                    document.close();
                }
                document = null;
                try {
                    if (os != null) {
                        os.close();
                    }
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                os = null;
            }



        }



        private class HeaderFooterPageEvent extends PdfPageEventHelper {

            PdfContentByte cb;
            PdfTemplate template;
            BaseFont  bf;
            Font f;
            float fs;

            public HeaderFooterPageEvent(BaseFont _bf) {
                super();
                bf = _bf;
                f = new Font(bf);
            }


            @Override
            public void onOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
                 cb = writer.getDirectContent();
                 template = cb.createTemplate(50, 50);
            }


             @Override
            public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
                Date dat = new Date();      
                ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
                ct.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(sdf.format(dat) ), 100, 30, 0);

                String text = "Page " +writer.getPageNumber() + " to ";
                float len = bf.getWidthPoint(text, 12);
                cb.beginText();
                cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 12);
                cb.setTextMatrix(450, 30);
                cb.showText(text);
                cb.endText();
                cb.addTemplate(template, 450 + len, 30);     
            }

            @Override
            public void onCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
                   template.beginText();
                   template.setFontAndSize(bf, 12);
                   template.showText(String.valueOf(writer.getPageNumber()));
                   template.endText();
            }

        }       
    }
```

When executed on the iSeries, we have the error message

```
    com.ibm.commerce.command.ECCommandTarget executeCommand CMN0420E: The following command exception has occurred during processing: "ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.". ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPages.writePageTree(PdfPages.java:112)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.close(PdfWriter.java:1256)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:900)
        at com.itextpdf.text.Document.close(Document.java:415)
        at be.ourcustomer.package.GeneratePDFCmdImpl.performExecute(GeneratePDFCmdImpl.java:107)
```

I don't have much idea about what we do wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The error tells you that no content whatsoever was added to the document. This means that `srcContent` is either empty, or HTML that can't be parsed by XML Worker.

Comment: Looks like It can't write the output stream.   You might have to use a writer that points to a folder on the iSeries.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your inputs. I also thought about some permission issue on the iSeries. 
After further investigations, we found the library for the xmlworker was missing on this environment, resulting in a empty document as stated by the error message.